# Calendar event, custom form

Tags: android, android-calendar

Is there a way to fill out the calendar for Droid 4.0 without using the built in form?

For example, I created my own form where the user fills out, and upon a button press, I want it to add the events to the calendar.

If that is not possible, can I somehow edit the built in form?

Currently, my program fills out my form, saves all the variables, and puts it in the default form. Thus the user has to click the submit button twice in order to register an event.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with **API 14 (Honeycomb)**, you can use `CalendarProvider` to read and write calendar events directly. 
You will obviously need to set the proper permissions in your manifest (`android.permission.READ_CALENDAR` and `android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR`).

Sadly, this is not supported on previous android versions...

Here is the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)